# Unable to connect FTP server from ADF

Tags: ftp, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to do some simple copy activity in ADF...

Input Dataset is a **FTP Server**

Output Dataset is a **Azure Blob Storage**

I have to copy all the **.XML** files from FTP server to my Azure blob storage

 This is my FTP server Remote path

[image]

This is my json **"folderPath": "Testing"** in azure portal

> ErrorCode=UserErrorFileNotFound,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Cannot find the file specified. Folder path: 'Testing', File filter: '*.txt'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=Unable to connect to the remote server,Source=System,'.

Can copy activity supports for .xml file?

Am I missing anything here?

Somebody Help me here to solve!

Thanks Jayendran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just missed to set up the SFTP config to access by azure Service